# Sending USB vendor specific commands to USB HUB?

Tags: windows, usb, msdn, drivers, winusb

I have USB 2.0 HUB which I can program,
when I connect the HUB to my PC, WINDOWS recognize it as standart USB 2.0 HUB ,and I see in the device manager that "iusb3hub.sys" is the driver.

is there any simple way to send "vendor specific" commands to the HUB?

I thought about writing WINUSB application but as I understand,  I will have to replace the driver and then windows will no recognize it as USB 2.0 HUB